# iframe code working in all browsers but IE 11

Tags: content-editor-web-part, internet-explorer, iframe, script-editor-webpart

I have a piece of code for an iframe that stopped working in IE 11 (doesn't work in a CEWP and Script Editor).  It will display as expected in Chrome, Edge, and FireFox but will not in IE 11.  I have other webparts in other parts of SharePoint that display iframes just fine ... it is just this one - it will not allow users to select the "Allow Cookies" to display content (the other browsers allowed users to accept cookies to display the content).  I have tried compatibility settings and code () - does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser console? Can you please share the code you are using in your CEWP or Script editor webpart?

Comment: @GaneshSanap  no error ... it is displaying the header of the expected content with a prompt for the user to "accept cookies" but does nothing when the button is clicked .... here is the code                                                                                                                         
           <div style="width: 650px; height: 800px; overflow: auto; padding-left: 20px; max-width: calc(100% - 25px);"> 
   <iframe src="Address here" style="border: currentcolor; width: 100%; height: 99%;"></iframe> </div>